# 1- Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module

Tags: javascript

Magento 2.1.17
Script trying to load, and developer cannot seem to locate. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){"use strict";Array.prototype.indexOf||(Array.prototype.indexOf=function(e,t){var a;if(null==this)throw new TypeError("'this' is null or undefined");var r=Object(this),i=r.length>>>0;if(0===i)return-1;var n=+t||0;if(Math.abs(n)===1/0&&(n=0),i<=n)return-1;for(a=Math.max(0<=n?n:i-Math.abs(n),0);a<i;){if(a in r&&r[a]===e)return a;a++}return-1});var e=function(e){this.options=this.extend(e,{swfContainerId:"siqfp",swfPath:"flash/compiled/FontList.swf",sortPluginsFor:[/palemoon/i]}),this.nativeForEach=Array.prototype.forEach,this.nativeMap=Array.prototype.map};return e.prototype={extend:function(e,t){if(null==e)return t;for(var a in e)null!=e[a]&&t[a]!==e[a]&&(t[a]=e[a]);return t},get:function(a){var e=[];e=this.userAgentKey(e),e=this.languageKey(e),e=this.colorDepthKey(e),e=this.screenResolutionKey(e),e=this.timezoneOffsetKey(e),e=this.sessionStorageKey(e),e=this.localStorageKey(e),e=this.indexedDbKey(e),e=this.addBehaviorKey(e),e=this.openDatabaseKey(e),e=this.cpuClassKey(e),e=this.platformKey(e),e=this.doNotTrackKey(e),e=this.pluginsKey(e),e=this.canvasKey(e),e=this.webglKey(e),e=this.adBlockKey(e),e=this.hasLiedLanguagesKey(e),e=this.hasLiedResolutionKey(e),e=this.hasLiedOsKey(e),e=this.hasLiedBrowserKey(e),e=this.touchSupportKey(e);var r=this;this.fontsKey(e,function(e){var t=r.x64hash128(e.join("~~~"),31);return a(t)})},userAgentKey:function(e){return e.push(this.getUserAgent()),e},getUserAgent:function(){return navigator.userAgent},languageKey:function(e){return

Answer (score 0):

Did you make cache:clean and Cache:flush?
You could also delete content of generated folder and then try again.